# How to extract common code into one method

Tags: scala

If I have an object with case classes inside it like this:

```
object Color {
  case class Shade (name: String)
  case class Type (myType: String)
  case class Available (isAvailable: Boolean)
}
```

and I have a method(s) like below:

```
def something(message: Shade) {
  ...
}
def something(message: Type) {
 ...
}
```

How can I make the above methods into just one (DRY principle) such that it accepts either `Shade` or `Type`?

Comment: Can you help me understand why these types are not a single type describing a `Color`, e.g. `case class Color(shade: String, typ: String, available: Boolean)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can abstract case classes and accept the abstract class as argument.

If you want to process based on concrete type then use pattern match on input as below.

```
  object Visitor {

    trait Message {
      def name: String
    }
    object Color {
      case class Shade (name: String) extends Message
      case class Type (name: String, myType: String) extends Message
      case class Available (isAvailable: Boolean)
    }

    def processSomething(message: Message): Unit = {
      message match {
        case Shade(name) => println(s"Shade: ${name}")
        case Type(name, myType) => println(s"Type: ${myType}")
      }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      processSomething(Shade("I'm shade"))
      processSomething(Type("I'm type", "I'm type"))
    }
  }
```

If case classes have no fields in common but if they somehow represent 
same thing, then you can have "marker interface"

```
 sealed trait Message
 case class Shade (myName: String) extends Message
 case class Type (myType: String) extends Message
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't realize my small example was not correct to the actual example. The property of the `Type` case class is `type` not `name`. This means I can't abstract the case class like you've shown. Is there another way?

Comment: If they have nothing in common, then you probably want to write separate functions. If they are common somehow then you can introduce something called "marker interface" in OO, which would be `trait Message` in scala

Comment: can "marker interface" be used for same type of property (i.e. string, int, etc) rather than actual `name` of the property? in your example if  `Type` case class was  `case class Type (myType: String) extends Message` it won't compile right?

Comment: Since "marker interface" means there are no abstractions defined but you can add as many properties to concrete classes as you want. So `case class Type (myType: String) extends Message` is completely fine when `Message` has nothing defined. See my second example. Hope that is helpful

Comment: And no trait can not be defined just for "types", trait define the behaviours. you have to pattern match as shown in above example to determine which concrete class it is, and extract properties based on that